# Passing a vector to if...else() with for()

Tags: r

I am trying to understand for-loops and if...else functions. Normally, one should use the apply-family instead of for-loops and most R functions are in any case vectorized. Thus many examples of using the for-loop are not very helpful. Also, since neither ?for nor ?if...else work (please tell me how to make them work), I am a bit lost.

Coming to my questions:

1) if...else cannot take vectors with more than one value. for() takes i of the given vector and passes it to a function. Why does the code below not work, or better said, why does for() not pass i as a single value to if...else successfully? Or is it a coding error?

2) If not, is there another way to do it?

```
x <- 1:10
funky <- function(x){
  out <- vector("list", length(x))
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    out[[i]] <-  if(x<3){
  x+1
  } else if (x==3){
    x+10
  }else{x+100}
  }
}
funky(x)
```

Comment: Do I need to add ```[i]``` in front of every x after the if? In that case exceuting the function does not return anything

Comment: Thanks joran! That worked : ))) Can I ask two more quick questions, which are not related, but I really want to know! How can I find out all the options of an argument of a given function? Is there a function to return them? Also, what do I type to make ? work for the for loop and if...else instead of ifelse?

Comment: @joran: Not entirely true, you can use `formals()` or `formalArgs()`. F.ex `formals(funky)` returns the arguments of `funky()`, including any defaults.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `x` is a vector, but you treat it as a single element. Other than that you need to return the result.

```
x <- 1:10

funky <- function(x) {
  out <- vector("list", length(x))
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    xi <- x[i]
    out[[i]] <-  if (xi < 3) {
      xi + 1
    } else if (xi == 3){
      xi + 10
    } else {
      xi + 100
    }
  }
  out
}

funky(x)
```

Comment: @spaniel this answer is 100% correct, but I wanted to point out that R also supports looping through a vector with `for` automatically: `for (var in x) { ... }` where `var` is variable name used to access the current value of `x` in your for loop. This prevents having to do `for (i in 1:length(x)) { xi <- x[i]; ... }` and is helpful if you just want to loop over each value and don't care about the "position" of the value.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the "is there another way to do it" question.

```
sapply(seq(1:10), function(x) ifelse(x<3, x+1,
                                      ifelse(x==3, x+10, x+100)))

 [1]   2   3  13 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```

Or if you want a standalone function:

```
x <- 1:10
funky <- function(x){
    ifelse(x<3, x+1, ifelse(x==3, x+10, x+100))}

> funky(x)
 [1]   2   3  13 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```

Or if you don't need a custom function:

```
x <- 1:10
ifelse(x<3, x+1, ifelse(x==3, x+10, x+100))

[1]   2   3  13 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```

Comment: Thanks! But sapply is not really necessary for the function to work, or is it? Also, I acutally wanted to use for() with if...else to understand these two functions better.

Comment: @Spaniel correct, `ifelse(x<3, x+1, ifelse(x==3, x+10, x+100))` works just fine without the `sapply`

Comment: Yes, if x is an existing object already. In my standalone answer it wasn't.